# ¿Cómo instalar el paquete AED en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Estuve buscando en el repositorio de R, pero al parecer este paquete ya fue eliminado. 
He buscado una copia en .zip, pero no la encuentro. Entonces, ¿cómo podría instalar ese paquete para usarlo en mi proyecto?

Comment: Hola Jorge te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Es cierto, el paquete ya no se encuentra más en CRAN sin embargo tienes el  github del mismo en: https://github.com/romunov/AED, deberías poder instalarlo desde esa ubicación sin demasiados inconvenientes.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando con lo comentado por Patricio, lo puedes instalar ejecutando una vez

```
source("https://install-github.me/romunov/AED")
```

Esto es similar a `install.packages` pero descargando desde el repositorio de github.

Answer (score -1):

Primero instala el paquete Remotes que permite la instalación de paquetes R desde repositorios remotos:

```
install.packages("remotes")
```

Luego indica qué paquete quieres instalar desde GitHub (en este caso AED):

```
remotes::install_github("romunov/AED")
```

Comment: Hola, las publicaciones que son sólo código sin ninguna explicación de lo que hacen o cómo resuelven el problema, se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para los usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir una breve descripción del código, dónde debe ponerse y qué es lo que hace para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Completa el [tour] y lee [answer] para más información.